# Using DataTables Plugin in Razor View - Cannot set properties of undefined (setting '_DT_CellIndex') Error

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, datatable

I am using a asp.net mvc web app. I have created a table and now I am wanting to use the plugin in [datatables](https://datatables.net/). I saw you only needed 3 lines of code to make this work. I attempted to do exactly what it required in order for it to work and give me the desired datatable, but it does not give me the table I am expecting. I even went to examples -> HTML (DOM) source data -> and under Javascript tab I entered the lines required.

**Is there something I am doing incorrect here with the script tags or is the plug in just not working?** I do not have the files downloaded and imported to my project.

Expecting a standard look like this [image]

But am getting this... so I am missing the look of the datatable plugin and the following Error.

> Cannot set properties of undefined (setting '_DT_CellIndex')

my view:

```
@model List<Fright>


@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
     var result = Model.GroupBy(gb => gb.Value);
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
    <link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.11.2/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.11.2/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" defer></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#homeTable').DataTable();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <table id="homeTable" class="display" style="width:100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Value</th>
                    <th>Option</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in result)
                {
                    var url = "/frightSummary/SummaryIndex?id=" + item.Key;
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <a href=@url>@item.Key</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you see any error in the developer console? (F12)

Comment: @Steve I just checked and saw that I am getting an error. I posted it on the post. Not sure why that is saying .DataTable is not a function but in the guide it shows it as so. Did I do it incorrectly?

Comment: I usually put everything in the _@section Scripts_ at the end of the file. Not sure if it does any difference.

Comment: Also shoudn't it be `_<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net..._`

Comment: So take everything (scripts) from the head and place that after the `</html>` line? In regards to the `<script src="cdn.datables.net..` I thought so too, but if you look on their website https://datatables.net/ on the left side of the page it says copy this and it includes the two forward slashes @Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is a mismatch in the number of `<td> </td>`. You are just rendering 1 `<td>` in `foreach` loop but you have two `<th></th>` in the table header

````
@model List<Fright>


@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
     var result = Model.GroupBy(gb => gb.Value);
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
    <link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.11.2/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.11.2/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" defer></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#homeTable').DataTable();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <table id="homeTable" class="display" style="width:100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Value</th>
                    <th>Option</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in result)
                {
                    var url = "/frightSummary/SummaryIndex?id=" + item.Key;
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <a href=@url>@item.Key</a>
                        </td>
                    <td>
                            <a href=@url>@item.Option</a> /* output you Option value*/
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html> ```
````

Comment: I see! Thank you! So with using their plug in the amount of <th> must match <td>?